# Do I violate the abstraction law?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

I have two variables, the first with the type `Either String Int` and the second with the type `IO (Either String Int)`.

As you can see, the structure of two variables are almost the same, except the second is wrapped into `IO`.

To make it composable, I am planing to lift both into MonadTransformer `EitherT`, but the first variable I have to lift into `IO`.

Is it wrong to lift the first variable into `IO` to make it composable, although there has no side effect happened on it.

It is just about to put into IO context.

Comment: What do you need `EitherT` for? To me, it looks like one of those values is simply contained in `IO`, whereas the other is not... You can trivially put the pure value into `IO` with `return`, or use monadic bind to compose them...

Comment: But I want to compose `Either String Int` inside the `IO` too. So think, I need `EitherT`, because it is going to compose  `Either String Int` too. So I think I could avoid boilerplate through `EitherT`. But it is ok, to lift something into `IO`, although there is no side effect meaning, in other words, can I pack everything into `IO` what ever I want?

Comment: What do you mean by *compose?* If `x` is an `Either String Int` value, then `return x` (or `pure x`) will have the type `IO (Either String Int)`... What goal are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can abstracting from concrete type. The first variable may has type  `MonadThrow m => m Int` and the second `(MonadIO m, MonadThrow m) => m Int`. They can be composable in different contexts.

Comment: I have `a :: IO (Either String Int)` and `b :: IO (Either String Int)`. Then use `a >>= b`, I have to ask always, if it is `Left` or `Right` in every `>>=` operation. Here is what I try to accomplish: https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_Transformers_Tutorial.

Comment: At the beginning of the tutorial, you can see the `do` block. Can you see the boilerplate code? That is what I am trying to avoid, pack `IO (Either String Int)` into `EitherT String IO Int`.

Comment: What do you mean by `a >>= b`? That's not going to compile, because the type of `>>=` is `Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. The second argument has to be a function, and `b` isn't a function. What are you actually trying to *accomplish?*

Comment: Sorry my mistake. `foo :: IO (Either String A)` and `boo :: a -> IO (Either String B)`.  `foo >>= \x -> case Left e ... Right  r ...`.  To avoid writing pattern matching all the time, I would use lift into context `EitherT`.

Comment: Ah, OK, now I get it! Sorry I was being dense. I don't see any problem with lifting a pure value into that context in order to compose it. It'd still be pure...

Comment: I am so sorry for my mistake. Awesome thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not wrong; in fact, [it is encouraged](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-2.2.2/docs/Control-Error-Util.html#v:hoistEither).